# Animated *.gif framerate is too high

Tags: java, swing

I'm loading an animated gif into a JButton. Online the gif looks to move at a normal pace. But when I load it in java it looks like the animation is trying to run as quickly as possible! How can I atleast slow it down?

Here is my code:

```
public Icon getIcon(){
  return new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("images/working.gif"), "Application is running.");
 }
```

Any ideas? Thanks guys 'n gals.

Comment: Please add link to the GIF in question.  Your delay is most likely incorrect in the GIF file.

Comment: waw.... that's right! thanks for giving an advice :D @Sandro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers tend to limit the framerate of GIFs. For example, I've read that Opera and IE will fix framerates slower than Firefox. [Here's an example of people seeing this effect.](http://www.devppl.com/forum/gif-slow-in-browser-vt6989.html)

The problem is likely that the delay in the animation is incorrect in the .gif itself, and viewing it in a browser is only masking the issue.

Comment: yes that was problem. I saved the gif with a new frame rate and it now works correctly. Thank you!